# Referencing FSharp.Core from Visual Web Developer Express

Tags: c#, .net, f#

I need to reference FSharp.Core to a Visual Web Developer Express project (C#), but for some reason when I click "Add Reference" it doesn't exist on the ".NET" list. Also tried to search this DLL on `C:\Program Files\Referenced Assemblies`, didn't find anything.

I downloaded this DLL from somewhere, but when I add it, it throws that System.Tuple exists in both mscorelib and FSharp.Core.

I'm using Visual Web Developer Express 2010 with .NET Framework 4 (*not* client profile).

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that you're referencing the .NET 2.0 version of the F# library?  It defines its own tuple types since the framework didn't have them until .NET 4.0.  I'd recommend looking for the .NET 4.0 version of FSharp.Core on your machine and referencing that, or re-downloading and installing F#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What @kvb said in his comment.  The version you want probably lives in a location like

C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\2.0\Runtime\v4.0\FSharp.Core.dll

Be sure you have the "v4.0" part.

Comment: I don't have FSharp directory in C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\

Comment: Then you probably need to install the F# CTP, the second link here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/fsharp/cc835251.aspx